# Is there a way to add a CC email address in SendGrid's Automation Email system?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am currently building an automation email in SendGrid. The [setup process](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/getting-started-with-automation) seems very straightforward, but I can't find how or where to add a CC email address.

I've researched SendGrid's documentation and other sites to find a possible solution. Two sources had the right idea, but they provided examples using Node.js (see [SendGrid Personalizations](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations) and [Twilio Blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-bulk-emails-3-ways-sendgrid-nodejs)). I am needing to add a CC address inside SendGrid's Automation Email creator.

Does the SendGrid Automation system provide this capability, or is this best achieved through Node.js (or other background-handling languages)?

Comment: I don't think you can add a cc to an automation in SendGrid. Can I ask why you would want a cc on each automation email though? I'm interested in the use-case and might be able to suggest other methods (or raise a feature request) when I understand.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can't share too much, but basically I need to add a CC so my company's sales team can also receive the emails and take appropriate action. As of now, customers only receive the automated email, and the sales team receives no indication of an email being sent. Whenever a customer posts a question, they receive an email stating their message was received, but the sales team receives no such alert. I would like to CC the sales team email, so both parties receive said email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can send an Automation with a cc.

You can track when Automation emails are sent to users by registering for the [Event Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook).

When users reply to the automation email and just get an email saying that their message was received, I assume that is because the email address you send the automation from is just set up to autorespond. You could set that email address up with the [Inbound Parse Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook) so that you can trigger other events when you receive emails to that address. You could, in that case, send an email to your sales team, or register the response in a database, or forward the message to a CRM system.

If the only solution for you is to use a cc, then Automations may not work for you and you will have to send using the [Mail Send API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send) which gives you lots more control over the email being sent, but does lose the automation features.

Comment: Thank you so much for these great details! After doing some additional research, I decided to use the Mail Send API because it provides the features I need for this project. The API allowed me to manipulate our dynamic templates for our auto-responses, which was amazingly helpful! Thank you again for your time in helping me understand more of the API and Webhook features. These will definitely come in handy for future projects!